# replacing variable in elements of a List

Tags: c#

A more simple example might be:

```
List <myElement> Elements;
Elements.Add(my1);
Elements.Add(my2);
```

my1 and my2 eache have a variable of type string named myString

Now I want to change the value of my1.myString. But if I change it the value my2.myString gets changed aswell.

Hopefully it's a bit clearer now

---

I'm using a List with several Elements within it in C#. The List has as type a self-defined class with several variables in it.

Now I want to change in one list-element the value of a variable. But unfortunately the value gets replaced not only on this but in all elements of this list.

Any advice on how to fix this?

```
MyProjectElement File1 = this.Project.Elements[0];
MyProjectElement File2 = this.Project.Elements[1];
MyProject my1 = (MyProject)File1;
MyProject my2 = (MyProject)File2;

PageCount_F1 = my1.PageCount;
PageCount_F2 = my2.PageCount;

if (PageCount_F1 != PageCount_F2)
MessageBox.Show("The 2 files need to have the same file length", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

else
{
my1.IncludeAllPages = false;
my2.IncludeAllPages = false;

for(int i=1; i <= PageCount_F1; i++)
{
    StringBuilder value1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder value2 = new StringBuilder();
    value1.Append("" + i);
    value2.Append("" + (PageCount_F2-i+1));
    MyProject my1new = new MyProject();
    MyProject my2new = new MyProject();
    my1new.Pages = value1.ToString();
    my2new.Pages = value2.ToString();
    my1.Pages = my1new.Pages;
    my2.Pages = my2new.Pages;

    this.Project.Elements.Add((myProjectElement)my1);
    this.Project.Elements.Add((myProjectElement)my2);

    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[1]).Pages.Remove(0);
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[i]).Pages.Remove(0);
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[1]).Pages = "" + 1;
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[PageCount_F2 - i + 1]).Pages = "" + (PageCount_F2 - i + 1);

    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[i-1]).Pages.Remove(0);
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[i]).Pages.Remove(0);
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[i - 1]).Pages = "" + i;
    ((MyProject)this.Project.Elements[i]).Pages = "" + (PageCount_F2 - i + 1);
}
```

Comment: This is not a simple, clear example.  Can you perhaps illustrate with a very short example?  Hard to tell what all your elements are in this due to the noise.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear with regards to the question versus the code posted?

Comment: For what it's worth, [here's the code with all the `"" + x` and formatting and indenting fixed](http://codepad.org/ibMxUgNn).

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what the condition is to make a change.  For example:

```
myList.ForEach(x => if(whateverCondition) x.myString = "blah" );
```

But you really need to ascertain what that condition is.

Comment: Hey Moo-Juice, thank you for the hint. I'll be trying it with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the code that you've put up you're changing your values in a loop that steps through every element and the loop starts indexing the List with index 1, whereas the first element in index 0.

If you're only after changing one element then select that element. Moo-Juice has posted a good suggestion (+1 btw).

p.s. don't post links to external stores with your code, many users that sit behind corporate firewalls can't access them.